# Processing lines from one text file to another

Tags: c++, stream, xcode5

I would like to give thanks to everyone who helped me with my problem. I was finally able to arrange the data by birth year! Very much appreciated. If anyone can help me with this final question, that'd be great

If I have lines in a text file that look like this:

```
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200 
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870
```

How can I output this data onto a new text file but only listing three things: year - name - time ... so that these two lines would look like this:

```
1979   Orvar Steingrimsson   4:48:08
1987   Gudni Pall Palsson    4:52:25
```

My guess was this:

```
ifstream in("inputfile.txt");
ofstream out("outputfile.txt");
int score, year;
string name, time, group, team;
while (getline(in,str));
in >> score >> time >> name >> year >> group >> team;
//and then do something like this
out << year << name << time << '\n';
```

However I have a feeling I won't be able to loop this through the whole text file and all 200 lines. Any tips appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I won't use C++ for this

Comment: What does that mean? I just started a C++ class and we're asked to do this. Huge assignment, due tonight, and I can't get help since I literally do not know a single person in my UNI. I know everyone else is just helping eachother out and sharing codes. But i have to do this myself, and sadly, in C++!

Comment: Why are you extracting 1st 2nd 3rd..6th line one by one ?

Comment: @P0W Why does he have a `return` in the middle of his `while`?  Why does he try to define a function  in the middle of a `while` loop?  I think we have to assume that this isn't real code, since it won't compile (and he's not asking about strange compiler errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I know that the year is always the 54th to 58th character in each line"*

So, consider this :

```
int main ()
{
    ifstream  in("laugavegurinn.txt", ios::in);
    ofstream out("laugavegurinn2.txt");
    string str;
    multimap<int, string> datayear;

    while (getline(in,str)) {
         int year = stoi(str.substr(54, 4));
         datayear.insert(make_pair(year,str)); //use insert function
         // multimap don't have [] operator
           }

    for (auto v : datayear) 
        out << v.second << "\n";

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: You, my best friend, are a lifesaver. Despite working on this for about a week and asking countless questions on this site, trying numerous ways and reading my C++ book over and over, nothing worked. Until you came along. Sincerely, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For starters, read the lines into an `std::vector<std::string>`,
using `std::getline`.  Then sort them in the desired order.
Then output them.  So `main` becomes basically three lines:

```
std::vector<Line> data( readLines( inFile ) );
sortByBirthYear( data );
std::copy( data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( outFile, "\n" ) );
```

Of course, `readLines` and `sortByBirth` need to be written as
well, but they're both fairly trivial as well.

Alternatively, and probably better, you could define
a `DataLine` class with an `operator>>`, and `operator<<` and
a comparison function (`operator<`), and then all you'd need is:

```
std::vector<DataLine> data(
    (std::istream_iterator<DataLine>( inFile )),
    (std::istream_iterator<DataLine>()) );
std::sort( data.begin(), data.end() );
std::copy( data.begin(),
           data.end(),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( outFile, "\n" ) );
```

That's what I'd do, but if you've just started C++, you may not
have covered the necessary basics yet, like classes and operator
overloading.

One thing I'd also add, based on your code: don't ever access
data you've input without first checking that the input
succeeded.

EDIT (implementation using just the basic functionality):

As above (but without the `Line` type):

```
std::vector<std::string> data( readLines( inFile ) );
std::sort( data.begin(), data.end(), orderByBirthYear );
std::copy( data.begin(), data.end(),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( outFile, "\n" ) );
```

with:

```
std::vector<std::string>
readLines( std::istream& source )
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( source, line ) ) {
        results.push_back( line );
    }
    return results;
}

bool
orderByBirthYear( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs )
{
    return lhs.compare( 54, 4, rhs, 54, 4 ) < 0;
}
```

But I insist: this is *not* how one should solve it.  Any
reasonable solution would start by defining a class for your
data, and define all of the operations using this.  This means
not just defining a `class`, but also operator overloading; if
you've just started, you likely haven't seen any of these yet
(and the assignment is not a good sign with regards to the
quality of the course).

For the rest, you're on the right track; for line oriented
input, you should read using `getline`.  After that, however,
the line has been extracted from the input; to parse it further,
you need to initialize an `std::istringstream` with it, and read
from that.  Except that your input format seems to be based on
columns, so you'd probably use the `substr` function of
`std::string` to get the individual fields.  Once you've got
them, you'll want to strip leading and trailing white space, and
maybe convert to numeric types (although for just sorting by
year, this is not necessary).  But all of this would logically
occur in a user defined `operator>>` to a `Data` class.
(Similarly, you'd provide a user defined `operator<<` to write
the sorted data out.  And typically, `orderByBirthYear`, above,
would be a class as well.)

Comment: Yeah, just started and we literally haven't covered sh**. Nonetheless, this is the project. Could you help me understand what you mean by define a DataLine class? I understand that I need to define it, as in
class DataLine {
.... but then what?

Comment: @MagnusOttiBenediktsson There's no way I could describe how to write a class in this forum; there's just too much.  I've edited with a rough draft as to how to do it without any additional classes, but this is _not_ the way to do it in real life.