# Sorting 200 lines in text file by 4 numbers that occur at same spot on each line

Tags: c++, sorting, stream, xcode5

I am trying to read a text file that has 200 lines looking like these four examples:

```
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200 
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870 
3    5:14:24   Ryan Paavola                        1984   18 - 29 ara      USA
4    5:18:43   Hendrik Sporing                     1990   18 - 29 ara      GER
```

Currently, the lines are organised by their time, as you can see, but I wish to organise them by the birthyear of each contestant, so that in this case, these four lines would look like this:

```
4    5:18:43   Hendrik Sporing                     1990   18 - 29 ara      GER
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870 
3    5:14:24   Ryan Paavola                        1984   18 - 29 ara      USA
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200
```

I am supposed to rearrange the lines according to the birthyear, and the input file is "laugavegurinn.txt" and the output file is "laugavegurinn2.txt"

Can anyone point out the problem with my code and/or suggest a better way to do this? Heads up, not very skilled with C++ and would appreciate any help at all. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream> //for basic functions
#include <fstream> //for basic file operations
#include <string> //for string operations
#include <map> //for multimap functions

using namespace std;

void process (istream &in, ostream &out) {
multimap<int, string> data_by_year;
string str;
while (getline(in,str)) {
    int year = stoi(str.substr(54, 4));
    data_by_year.insert(make_pair(year, str));
}
for (auto v : data_by_year) {
    out << v.second << "\n";
}
}

int main () {
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    in.open("laugavegurinn.txt");
    out.open("laugavegurinn2.txt");

    process(in, out);
}
```

Comment: the reason for substr(54,4) is because on the text file, the birthyears are always the 54th-58th character on each line.

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: You asked [again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19055100/1870232) ?

Comment: @P0W Probably not the same guy, just someone in the same course... This is getting more frequent recently, you can always tell when it's 5 hours until coursework deadline at some college...

Comment: Yeah, recently there was a burst of parenthesis-matching-using-a-stack questions also

Comment: Looks like this line won't compile: `out << v.second << "\n";`.  Try pointer de-reference (`->`) I don't see anything else wrong here.  (PS - Stop pretending you have no skill.  New?  Sure.  Unskilled?  Pishaw.)

Answer (score 0):

This is working right? You're just looking for improvements.

The usual way to do this would be to add all the lines unsorted to a `std::vector<std::string>` and then call `std::sort` with a custom ordering to sort into the desired order, then print out.

Should be a little more efficient than your solution (which is pretty good anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `str.substr(54 ,4)`, you could have used the following method (using character positions is error prone if the format ever changes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string myString = "Three    separate    tokens";

    istringstream iss(myString);
    auto it = istream_iterator<string>(iss);
    string thirdToken = *(it ++ ++);

    cout << thirdToken;
}
```

This directly reads the third word, regardless of its position or length.