# rearrange columns of lines in text file

Tags: c++, stream, xcode5

I have a text file with 200 lines that look like this:

```
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200 
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870
```

My code sorts these lines by the birth year of each contestant instead of the time as it does in the above example. So now the lines are sorted as such: (only a lot more lines)

```
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870 
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200
```

My question is how can I now make  listing three things: year - name - time ... so that these two lines would look like this:

```
1987   Gudni Pall Palsson    4:52:25  
1979   Orvar Steingrimsson   4:48:08
```

My code, so far, which sorts the lines in the right order:

```
#include <iostream> //for basic functions
#include <fstream> //for basic file operations
#include <string> //for string operations
#include <map> //for multimap functions

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
ifstream  in("laugavegurinn.txt", ios::in);
ofstream out("laugavegurinn2.txt");
string str;
multimap<int, string> datayear; //creates multimap linking each line to year

in.ignore(80);//ignores header of the file - 80 characters - to escape problems with while loop

// while (getline(in,str)) {
 //   string name = str.substr(18,30);
   // string time = str.substr(8,7);

//}


while (getline(in,str)) {
    int year = stoi(str.substr(54, 4));
    datayear.insert(make_pair(year,str)); //insert function and pairs year and string 
}

for (auto v : datayear)
    out << v.second << "\n";

in.close();
out.close();
}
```

Comment: I can't create the varibles name and time and then add them to the line: out << v.first << name << time << "\n\;

Comment: What shall be the third version of this question ? First being [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19055100/1870232). I'm wondering is this a [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397) problem ?

Comment: If all lines are arranged in the same order, you could get out each single information of a string with #include stringstream Arranging all the Information might be possible with some std::vector construct and then you just need to print out the right indexes. Did I get you problem right?

Comment: haha sorry. I've pretty much completed the project, but for the sakes of making it look nice, I'd like to arrange the columns: year - name - time....Although I very much appreciate all the help that I've gotten so far which enabled me to sort the data by year in the first place.

Comment: @Martin, yes you did. I'm going to play around with creating vectors for each piece of information. This isn't a neccessity, I just wanted to fix my solution as much as possible. Thanks

Comment: Are the columns tab-delimited, or fixed-width?

Comment: Hopefully you've the fixed position of "time" and "name" (start column) like the year, so using those, grab the time and name and arrange accordingly, else use `sstream`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a class or structure with one member representing each column in the table.  One instance represents one row.

From this class, you can write methods to display the data in any order you wish.

You can write ordering classes to sort the objects by any member.

Search StackOverflow for "reading from file" for examples on reading data from a file.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating each line as a single string: the only way to rearrange the fields is to extract each field and output separately. My example uses a struct with the fields you want to output.

```
#include <iostream> //for basic functions
#include <fstream> //for basic file operations
#include <string> //for string operations
#include <map> //for multimap functions

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  int year;
  string name;
  string time;
} Fields;

int main ()
{
  ifstream  in("names.txt", ios::in);
  ofstream out("namesout.txt");
  string str;
  multimap<int, Fields> data; //creates multimap linking each line to year

  in.ignore(80);

  Fields tempField;

  while (getline(in,str)) {
    tempField.year = stoi(str.substr(51, 4));
    tempField.name=  str.substr(15, 30);
    tempField.time=  str.substr(5, 8);
    data.insert(make_pair(tempField.year,tempField)); //insert function and pairs year and string
  }

  for (auto v : data)
    out << v.second.year << " " << v.second.name  << " " << v.second.time<< "\n";

  in.close();
  out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real easy way to do this. What I think you should do is read each line one at a time and parse them into a struct of some sort. Then display/write the appropriate items as you wish.

The tricky part is when you try to parse the person name. As a person's name may consist of multiple strings. Thus making the identification of the name part hard.

Pretty much the same as what **vinaut** said.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
2    4:52:25   Gudni Pall Palsson                  1987   18 - 29 ara      IS870
1    4:48:08   Orvar Steingrimsson                 1979   30 - 39 ara      IS200

$ sed -r 's/[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]:]+)[[:space:]]+(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]{4})[[:space:]].*/\3 \2 \1/' file
1987 Gudni Pall Palsson 4:52:25
1979 Orvar Steingrimsson 4:48:08
```